# Is every reduced $k$-algebra all of whose residue fields are $k$ finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, model-theory

Let $k$ be a field (of characteristic zero if you want). Let $A$ be a reduced $k$-algebra with the property that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ the natural homomorphism $k \to A/ \mathfrak{p}$ is an isomorphism.

Is $A$ necessarily a finitely generated $k$-algebra?

My first thought was that the direct product $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} k$ should be an obvious counter example. But I think that any non-principal ultra filter on $\mathbb{N}$ gives us a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that the residue field is not $k$.

Edit: So since there are counter examples for finite fields (see comments), I want to assume that the characteristic of $k$ is zero.

Comment: If $k$ is a finite field of order $q$ then $x^q = x$ for all $x$ in a direct  product of copies of $k$, so any quotient integral domain must be $k$. Therefore in that special case your guess about a problem coming from nonprincipal ultrafilters does not occur.

Comment: @KCd primarily I am interested in the case where $k$ has characteristic zero. but thanks for your answer, that's a cool argument.

Comment: @ZhenLin so under which conditions precisely does it imply artinian? KCd's comment shows that for finite fields it does not imply artinian right?

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered. Your hypothesis implies that $A$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: I think the example provided in [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/79284/68913) shows that the answer is "no". (I only had a very quick look, so this might not be true.)

Comment: To elaborate, I think that [this answer on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/118553/221584) shows that the example given in the first link is zero-dimensional and we thus have $R/\mathfrak{p} = R_\mathfrak{p} = k$ where the last equality is stated in the first link.

Comment: Less trivially and more interestingly, the ring is Von Neumann regular. It would be artinian iff noetherian